# Lucene Phrase Query and Tokenized Indexing

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, tokenize, phrase

I have a weird problem searching a lucene tokenized index with a phrase query.

I create the index in the following way

```
Document doc = new Document();
FieldType ft = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
ft.setTokenized(true);
Field field1 = new Field("key", "T-Test 1", ft); 
doc.add(field1)
Field field2 = new Field("key", "T-Test 2", ft); 
doc.add(field2)    
Field field3 = new Field("key", "T-Test 3", ft); 
doc.add(field3)    
Field field4 = new Field("key", "T-Test", ft); 
doc.add(field4)
```

I use the WhitespaceAnalyzer to tokenize the values.
If I want now search the String "T-Test" I get as result the values
T-Test 1,T-Test 2, T-Test 3, T-Test

I create the query in the following way.

```
PhraseQuery query = new PhraseQuery();
query.add(new Term("key","T-Test"));
query.setSlop(0);      
BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();
mainQuery.add(query, Occur.MUST);
```

I tryed also useing the ComplexPhraseQueryParser with the same effect. I just get all T-Test values. But I just want the T-Test and not the "T-Test 1,T-Test 2 and T-Test 3" 
Could anyone help me please.
Im close to become desperate
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just use the Stringfield for the problem. This solution works perfectly fine.

```
FieldType ft = new FieldType(StringField.TYPE_STORED);
ft.setTokenized(true);
StringField field = new StringField(key, value,Field.Store.YES);
```